# Having params inside a multiline sh script in a jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: parameters, jenkins-pipeline, sh

Hi given the following in a stage of my pipeline

```
sh """#!/bin/bash -xe
aws lambda create-function --region us-east-1 --role ${params.role} --handler ${params.handler} --runtime ${params.runtime} --function-name ${params.name} --zip-file fileb:///tmp/function.zip &&

VERSION=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name ${params.name}  | jq -r .Version) &&

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name DEV --function-version $VERSION && 

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name TEST --function-version $VERSION && 

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name PROD --function-version $VERSION  
"""
```

I keep getting error

> ```
>  workflowScript: 22: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
>    solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 22, column 178.
>     --function-name ${params.name} --zip-fi
> ```

Ive tried with ''' and """

I need it to substitute the various params out and also use the VERSION

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the `$` by the VERSION. In general in double quotes any `$` is evaluated in the current groovy context and then send to the `sh` command to be evaluated in the executor context. Hence you need to be very careful around those.

```
sh """#!/bin/bash -xe
aws lambda create-function --region us-east-1 --role ${params.role} --handler ${params.handler} --runtime ${params.runtime} --function-name ${params.name} --zip-file fileb:///tmp/function.zip &&

VERSION=\$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name ${params.name}  | jq -r .Version) &&

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name DEV --function-version \$VERSION && 

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name TEST --function-version \$VERSION && 

aws lambda update-alias --function-name ${params.name} --name PROD --function-version \$VERSION  
"""
```

Comment: and the ${params.xxx} ones? Do they need escaping as well?